# Combobox' SelectedItem bound to a DependencyProperty is not refreshing

Tags: wpf, binding, combobox, dependency-properties, selecteditem

I have a combobox, whose SelectedItem is bound to a dependency property.

```
public IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<int,string>> AllItems
{
    get { return _AllItems; }
    set
    {
        _AllItems = value;
        this.NotifyChange(() => AllItems);
    }
}

public KeyValuePair<int, string> SelectedStuff
{
    get { return (KeyValuePair<int, string>)GetValue(SelectedStuffProperty); }
    set
    {
        SetValue(SelectedStuffProperty, value);
        LoadThings();
    }
}

public static readonly DependencyProperty SelectedStuffProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("SelectedStuff", typeof(KeyValuePair<int, string>), typeof(MyUserControl), new UIPropertyMetadata(default(KeyValuePair<int, string>)));
```

And the xaml:

```
<ComboBox DisplayMemberPath="Value"
          ItemsSource="{Binding AllItems}"
          SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedStuff, Mode=TwoWay}" />
```

The data is correctly bound and displayed, but when I select another value in the combobox, the `set` is not called, neither is my `LoadThings()` method called.

Is there an obvious reason ?

Thanks in advance

---

## Edit

I used snoop to view inside the combobox, and when I change the value, the combobox' SelectedItem is also changed.
I also checked in the code, and the property is changed.  But my method is not called (as I don't go through the `set`, so the problem is still there...

Comment: Is there a reason SelectedStuffProperty needs to be a `DependencyProperty`?  This takes much of the control out of your hands and puts it in the framework's court.  Most situations like this only require a standard property that raises a Property Changed notification.

Comment: Yes, it is part of a UserControl, from which I must get this value via a binding in the parent container.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I found how to do that.

I declare my DependencyProperty using the overload woth the callback like this:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty SelectedStuffProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("SelectedStuff", typeof(KeyValuePair<int, string>), typeof(MyUserControl), new UIPropertyMetadata(default(KeyValuePair<int, string>), new PropertyChangedCallback(SelectedStuffChanged));
```

And in the callback, I do this:

```
private static void SelectedStuffChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    MyUserControl c = d as MyUserControl;
    c.LoadThings();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms753358.aspx#checklist)

> In all but exceptional circumstances, your wrapper implementations
>   should perform only the GetValue and SetValue actions, respectively.
>   The reason for this is discussed in the topic XAML Loading and
>   Dependency Properties.

And [there](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb613563.aspx) you can read

> The WPF XAML processor uses property system methods for dependency
>   properties when loading binary XAML and processing attributes that are
>   dependency properties. This effectively bypasses the property
>   wrappers.

Comment: Thanks for the information, I understand now why I can't use the breakpoint!