# changing binding based on datatrigger property

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, properties, datatrigger

I'm trying to change the text of a textblock based on a datatrigger. The datatrigger looks like this:

```
    <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=ShowFileExtensionsProperty}" Value="true">
            <Setter Property="Text" Value="{Binding Path=Name}" />
        </DataTrigger>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=ShowFileExtensionsProperty}" Value="false">
            <Setter Property="Text" Value="{Binding Path=NameWithoutExtension}" />
        </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

This code is found within the xaml file of the class "MyView" The cs file of this class contains the following code:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty ShowFileExtensionsProperty =
DependencyProperty.Register("ShowFileExtensions", typeof(bool), typeof(MyView), new UIPropertyMetadata(false));

public bool ShowFileExtensions
{
    get { return (bool)GetValue(ShowFileExtensionsProperty); }
    set
    {
        SetValue(ShowFileExtensionsProperty, value);
        updateViewCollection();
    }
}
```

The textblock is displayed within a listview, that has been bound to a list of objects, these objects contain the property "Name" and "NameWithoutExtension".

The problem is that the text in the textblock always stays blank. Somehow the datatrigger is never triggered. Any idea what is wrong with the datatriggers?

PS: The full code follows

```
<UserControl x:Class="com.xploreplus.Filedrops.explorer.listview.FiledropsFileList"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:l="clr-namespace:com.xploreplus.Filedrops.explorer.listview.views"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
<UserControl.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="Extension" TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=ShowFileExtensionsProperty, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}}" Value="true">
                <Setter Property="Text" Value="brol2" />
            </DataTrigger>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=ShowFileExtensionsProperty, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}}" Value="false">
                <Setter Property="Text" Value="blabla" />
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>

</UserControl.Resources>

<Grid>
    <ListView Name="viewComponent">
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <GridViewColumn Header="">
                    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                <Image Width="16" Height="16" Source="{Binding Path=Icon}" />
                            </StackPanel>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Name">
                    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource Extension}" />
                            </StackPanel>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Extension" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Extension}" />
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
</Grid>
```

Comment: This may be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16697392/620360

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the textblocks are shown in listview then the DataContext of textblock will the ItemDataContext if not set explicitly. That is why your bindings are not working. You will have to provide the relativesource to binding

Try updating the bindings like

```
<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=ShowFileExtensions, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}}" Value="true">
```

used {x:Type Control} assuming this is the type of your view else you will have to change to your view type.

Hope this helps

Thanks

Comment: The type in my case was UserControl. So I changed it to: <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=ShowFileExtensionsProperty, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}}" Value="true"> Unfortunatley, it didn't work. The text is still blank.

Comment: are you getting any exception in output window regarding this binding?

Comment: No, there are no exceptions. The text just stays blank.

Comment: This is strange that the output window of Visual Studio is not showing any exception and still binding is failing. Can you share the complete code where you are setting this style and of your listbox

Comment: This is not accessible here. You can update your question itself. Just wanted to see the listview and style application.

Comment: I changed the original question. Any suggestions on what I might do wrong?

Comment: where and how are you setting the ItemsSource for the listview? Also where are you setting the DataContext of your UserControl>?

Comment: I've set the itemsSource in the codebehind file with this line: viewComponent.ItemsSource = viewCollection; (with viewCollection being a list of appropriate objects). And no dataContext has been set.

Comment: hell, dint notice it should be Binding Path=ShowFileExtensions not Binding Path=ShowFileExtensionsProperty :( Pls see the updated answer. Rest relative source should be same